# SQL Server DATEADD function not working with PDO Sqlsrv extension

Tags: sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv, dateadd

I am using PDO with `Sqlsrv` extension to connect to a SQL Server database. This query works fine when I run it in any SQL Server database client but in PHP source code it does not produce result.

```
SELECT session 
FROM t_php_session 
WHERE php_session_id = 'p64aqbh15u6t35tq2h8n0bluq0' 
  AND user_ip = '127000000001' 
  AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, created) >= GETDATE()
```

While debugging I observed that when I remove the `DATEADD` condition from the `WHERE` clause, then it works fine and return the result. But I am not sure what is wrong with this condition.

Here is my sample source code:

```
$session_id = 'p64aqbh15u6t35tq2h8n0bluq0';
$interval = 30;
$ip = '127000000001';
$query = "SELECT session FROM t_php_session WHERE php_session_id = ? AND user_ip = ? AND DATEADD(MINUTE, ?, created) >= GETDATE()";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($session_id, $ip, $interval));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

This is my SQL Server database table structure:

[image]

I also tried assigning values by using **bindParam** method instead of passing an array in **execute** statement but that could not work too.

**SOLUTION**

After getting solution from @Your Common Sense i made following changes and it worked.

```
$query = "SELECT session FROM t_php_session WHERE php_session_id = ? AND user_ip = ? AND DATEADD(MINUTE, ?, created) >= GETDATE()";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $session_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $interval, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I don't think you can parameterize the `INTERVAL` part of `DATEADD`.

Comment: Thanks @wewesthemenace !!! You saved my day. You may like to add this comment as an answer and i would like to upvote it :)

Comment: Whats is your sql server version?DATEADD parameter might not be the problem.

Comment: I know but this is also the first parameter for DATEADD function in which you like to convert datetime field. In my case i am passing 30 minutes interval.Anyways it worked for me. Many thanks !!

Comment: No need to bracket the Minute. It's used in the DateAdd. I haven't any issue using it without a bracket. In any version of SQL Server. ;-)

Comment: For better performance you should always use the function on the value, not the column: "created >= dateadd(minute, -30, GETDATE())" instead of "DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, created) >= GETDATE()"

Comment: I deleted my answer as I don't have enough knowledge on PHP. You may want to see @Your Common Sense's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer obviously makes the **whole idea of prepared statements spoiled.**

Your code should positively work, if you bind a number using `PDO::PARAM_INT`.
At least in `emulation mode` this would work.

Comment: Can we pass array in execute statement along with using bindParam ?

Comment: Is it possible to provide same code which you think should work in my given example